# Unhandled Runtime Error - Error: Cannot find module 'crypto'

Tags: error-handling, cryptography

i had this error when working on a nextjs project
can anyone that had same issue, give me insights on the solution or the source of such error.
Thank you!

Call Stack
updateDehydratedSuspenseComponent
node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js (17414:18)
updateDehydratedSuspenseComponent
node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js (17110:15)
updateSuspenseComponent
node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js (18433:13)
beginWork$1
node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js (26791:13)
beginWork
node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js (25637:11)
performUnitOfWork
node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js (25353:4)
workLoopSync
node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js (25308:6)
renderRootSync
node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js (24432:73)
callback
node_modules/next/dist/compiled/scheduler/cjs/scheduler.development.js (256:33)
workLoop
node_modules/next/dist/compiled/scheduler/cjs/scheduler.development.js (225:13)
flushWork
node_modules/next/dist/compiled/scheduler/cjs/scheduler.development.js (534:20)

I tried ignoring that to package.json as solution but didn't work:

"browser": {
"crypto": false,
"stream": false
},